# Can't access file in app engine java

Tags: google-app-engine

I realize similar questions have been asked and answered but doing everything that is mentioned there I can't seem to get this to work.

in appengine-web. xml file I have

```
<resource-files>
  <include path="war/WEB-INF/StaticFiles/*" />
</resource-files>
```

I have a Test.txt file in the StaticFiles/ that I want to read so I

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("war/WEB-INF/StaticFiles/Test.txt"));
```

I get a FileNotFoundException.  If I change the path of the FileReader to say /WEB-INF/StaticFiles/Test.txt" I get a can't access denied error.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try leaving `war/` off of both parts of that.